# Calling a python module on button click using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to do a button disable followed by module calling and then button enable on the 'command' of a different button. However when I run this code, the button disable and label text change does not happen and the module is executed instead followed by the code after the module call.

button that is clicked calls 'set'

```
    btn_start = tk.Button(
        text="Start",
        width= 10,
        height= 3,
        bg="grey",
        fg="black",
        relief= 'raised',
        command = set
 )
```

---

```
import aatest4



def set():
    btn_exit["state"] = "disabled"
    label_a['text'] = 'Running'
    aatest4.run_script() #the imported module is run and the predecessor 'disabled' and 'text ' do not run
    btn_exit["state"] = "normal"
    label_a['width'] = 15
    label_a['text'] = 'Run Complete. Exit.'
```

Can someone guide as to what am I doing wrong, is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: When `aatest4.run_script()` is running, tkinter cannot update the widgets.  Add `root.update_idletasks()` (assume `root` is the root window) before `aatest4.run_script()`.

Comment: \\\The set is valid for Python. Use underscore def _set():